# SonarQube /sonar.sh start -> Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Small question regarding SonarQube please.

I have a MacBook Pro with a M1 chip, Apple silicon.
Just downloaded the version 9.3 of SonarQube from official website.

I went under the `bin/macosx-universal-64` folder in order to run the `start` command.

Unfortunately, I am getting this error: `./sonar.sh: line 424: /Users/me/sonarqube-9.3.0.51899/bin/macosx-universal-64/./wrapper: Bad CPU type in executable`

While I first thought this might be entirely related to the M1 chip, I see many from the community who managed to run SonarQube 9.3 on M1 chip without special settings.

Therefore, I am writing this, trying to understand what is wrong with this `./sonar.sh: line 424: /Users/me/sonarqube-9.3.0.51899/bin/macosx-universal-64/./wrapper: Bad CPU type in executable` and how to fix this.

Thank you